# Javascript variables conflict in different files

Tags: javascript, named-scope

I have declared two variables with the same name using the const keyword in two different javascript files. But still I get an error when I import both the files together to a web page.

I know that var declares global scope variables which would conflict but I had heard that const and let do not bahave like that.

How do I fix this.

Comment: You need to check if const variables are declared globally in a file OR outside of any method.
If you have declared them outside of any method of closure, then it automatically available globally.

Comment: It will be good if you give more clarification and post your code.

Comment: Post your code and pride an example

Comment: Yeah I have declared them without any block. That is what I want to know if can make them to not interfere but still making them available for all the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for an easy solution, having code blocks in the files will work, either as a self executing function or just a plain block:

```js
// On both files
(function(){
    const x = 123;
})();

// or just a code block
{
    const x = 456;
}
```

However, this is usually fixed by using a preprocessing tool like webpack (and organizing your code into modules to keep things separate), or at least having different classes and functions.

Comment: But I need the variables to be accessible across multiple functions in the same file and are the variables always going to conflict?

Comment: @ArpitGupta you can have functions inside the file-wide code blocks. When you're in the top-most scope of the files, your variables will conflict because they are in the global scope.